# GPX to Feature loses elevation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.3, elevation, gpx

I have been sent a GPX file to create a trails network on arcgis. When I run the GPX to Feature tool the elevation attributes are all zero, however when I view the GPX file on an online view, there is an elevation profile.

I am not familiar with the properties of GPX files, is it possible the GPX data has no elevation with it and is showing a profile on the viewers (e.g. maplorer) based on google maps?

In which case, can I add elevation data to the shapefile some other way?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [DNRGPS](http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/DNRGPS/DNRGPS.html) to do the conversion. I usually use this for tracklogs and other raw data types in gpx format.